# C# WCF TestClient curious on webconfig

Tags: c#, wcf, timeout, wcftestclient

just checking why is that the configured in sendTimeOut is 5 mins even though i set it to 10 mins, does test client follows the correct configuration on wcf?

thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean you set sendTimeOut in endpoint of client in service side? There are two kinds of sendTimeOut, service side and client side. For sendTimeout in Client.dll.config, it is test configure for client side in WCF Test Client, but it is not related with anything in service side or client configuration. It is a configure file in disk, you could right click Config File in Test client, and copy the full path to find the real file. If you want to set it in WCF Test Client, you could right click Configure file in WCF Test Client, Bindings->check the SendTimeout for the special binding.

Comment: i set the send timeout in the webservice web.config in IIS, even i set the sendTimeOut 10 minutes the WCF TestClient did not follow the configuration.

Comment: No, Client settings are not related with web.config in IIS. It is related with configure file in disk something like "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Temp\Test Client Projects\12.0\366d91c1-ed1e-4365-b49f-ed2ec6f946bb\Client.dll.config". You could try my above steps to get the file path